# can i call model from other views in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

Say I have a model called Book. I have a controller named books and related views for this model. Is it possible if I have another controller work with the model Book?

Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works inside any Controller, View or Model. To refer your model use upper cased class name. For example: Book

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But, why would you want to do that? What is the usecase?

Comment: as i would like to hidden the path. and then i found that i can use the route mapping for this purpose. what a stupid i am. :)

thanks buddy :)